# Why am getting a MultipleObjectsReturned error inside a try block?

Tags: python, django, exception

Any help on this one would great.  I'm using python 2.7 and django 1.2 Here's my code:

```
for save in saved: #list to iterate
    try:
        sect = obj.get(name=save) #obj is a RelatedManager
    except: #if two sections have the same name
        sect = obj.filter(name=save)
    else:
        #finish my code
```

I get a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error everytime when it hits the `get()` statement.  I'm no expert at python so I imagine I missed something simple.

Comment: Can you show the traceback?

Comment: I was facing same issue. Using `filter` instead of `get` fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

Two objects have the `name` values equal to the value of `save`

When using `get` and there are more than 1 row returned it raises [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#multipleobjectsreturned)

I think you should catch this explicitly because your except as it stands will also catch `DoesNotExist` errors (and all oteher errors)

```
    from django.core.exceptions import MultipleObjectsReturned

    try:
        sect = obj.get(name=save) #obj is a RelatedManager
    except MultipleObjectsReturned: #if two sections have the same name
        sect = obj.filter(name=save)[0]
    else:
        #finish my code
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you have more than 1 record in the database with name=save. Use filter() and get the one at index 0 if you want just one or properly handle that case separately .